# Why does one of my images not show on Gatsby page?

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am a bit lost on this one, so here it goes: I made a site with Gatsby.js and just deployed it to my web server (running NGINX on Ubuntu 20.04). For querying and displaying images I use **Gatsby Image** and everything seems to be working fine, there is ***just one*** image not being displayed - despite the file actually existing.

To see what I'm talking about, feel free to go to http://www.junge-philharmonie-berlin.de/ and see the logo left of "Junge Philharmonie Berlin" missing / not being displayed. In the source code, the DOM element is existent and also the src-path leads to an existing image; this is what I don't understand.

Any hint or help on this is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Marcus

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is present, you can grab it and check that is there in the inspect tools. Your issue relies on your CSS rules. You have:

```
.titleIcon {
    width: 37%;
    opacity: 1%;
}
```

If you change the opacity to `100%` (or `1`):

[image: Logo displayed]

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I was just wondering why this only happened on Prod and nowhere else. Seems to have been some js script that changed that value, because in my css it was actually set to 80%. Thanks a lot!!